# android - PopupMenu snap to selection?

Tags: android, android-layout, selection, popupmenu, snapping

My (admittedly long) PopupMenu's items are the integers from 10 to 99 (radio buttons).  The default selection is 48.  I would like the menu to snap to the selected value when it opens.  PopupMenu appears to lack this functionality.  Is there an easy workaround?

Comment: `PopupMenu` isn't very flexible. You could try using a `ListPopupWindow`, which is what PopupMenu wraps, but you would need to manually handle positioning against an anchor. You can probably copy most of this logic out of PopupMenu.java in the Android framework code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  The snapping isn't important enough to justify this much effort for now.  My 1.0 (version that is---hopefully not volume of!) users will just need to give the menu a good upward sling when they want to change the default selection to anything higher than 30 or so.

Comment: This really ought to be easier to accomplish -- would you mind filing a feature request on https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list? I'll assign it to myself.

Comment: @alanv it is at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=153536&thanks=153536&ts=1424471627